# Scatterplot with developmental trajectories

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw developmental trajectories in the plot below, i.e. the points 2009 and 2010 should be connected by a line with an arrow (pointing at 2010), the points 2010 and 2011 should be connected by a line with an arrow (pointing at 2011) and so on ...

This should apply to both groups.

Here is what I did so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- c(100, 200, 300, 200, 500, 320, 300, 50)
y <- c(100, 250, 600, 700, 60, 120, 200, 360)
t <- rep(seq(2009,2012),2)
z <- rep(c("A","B"),each=4)

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(z,t,x,y))
d <- d[order(d$z, d$t),]

ggplot(data = d, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = z, label=t)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text()
```

[image]

My 2 issues are: (1) the "wrong" points are connected and (2) the arrow heads are missing.

Comment: For (1) try `geom_path` instead, and note the `arrow` argument to help with (2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add an additional column `z2` to get `ggplot2` to see each line as a separate segment. Otherwise, only at the end of each group of segments an arrowhead was drawn. The code explains best:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

x <- c(100, 200, 300, 200, 500, 320, 300, 50)
y <- c(100, 250, 600, 700, 60, 120, 200, 360)
t <- rep(seq(2009,2012),2)
z <- rep(c("A","B"),each=4)
z2 <- LETTERS[1:length(z)]

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(z,z2,t,x,y))
d <- d[order(d$z, d$t),]

ggplot(data = d, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = z2, label=t)) + 
  geom_path(aes(group = z), arrow = arrow(ends = "last")) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text()
```

...and the result

[image]

Now you only need to tweak the colorscale a bit, or use a different aesthetic for `z2`.

Comment: That was fast. Thanks for your help!